# Regex wildcard to match time doesn't work in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I simply need to make this: `/2011 0:00`, to be this instead: `/2011`,

I tried using `/2011 *`, in find and replace with no luck. Can someone please point me in the right direction with a screencap for the find and replace screen

[image: regex attempt]

I should clarify that there is alot of text after the values I want to replace so I would appreciate how to prevent it deleting the rest of the text if anyone knows

Comment: You probably want to use `/2012 .*,` otherwise you're just matching any number of spaces after `2012`.

Comment: FYI, `*` is not a wildcard in regular expressions, `.` is. `*` in regexes is a quantifier that means "match 0 or more times". So taken together, `.*` means "match anything 0 or more times".

Comment: If all you wanted to do was replace `/2011 0:00` with `/2011`, why not just search for `/2011 0:00`? Please clarify your question, as it's currently written, it's unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a character other than space before your `*`

```
/2011 .*?,
```

http://rubular.com/r/3bowlutfkt

in some scripting languages, `*` is just a wild card for everything, but in regex, it means repeat the symbol before the `*` 0 or more times.  the `.` is a symbol that represents any one character.

Comment: Thanks that worked - but it deleted the rest of the line after the ',' - is there a way to keep everything after?

Comment: @chris yeah, you can make the regex non-greedy(that means it will take the minimum number of characters) by adding a `?` after the `*`.  I've updated my answer